# How to optimize the multiple hierarchy Avro producer code

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

The following is my Kafka Avro producer code, Because I need send a record with array and records types, so I used three schemas. It works, but it looks messy, Is there any good way to make the code more clean and tidy please.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String ip = "localhost";
    String url = "http://"+ip+":8081";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", ip+":9092");

    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
    props.put("schema.registry.url", url);

    String schemaRecord = "{\"namespace\": \"rdma.avro\", \"type\": \"record\", " + "\"name\": \"iprecord\","
            + "\"fields\": [" 
            + "{\"name\": \"ip\", \"type\": \"string\"},"
            + "{\"name\": \"count\", \"type\": \"long\"}"
            + "]}";

    String schemaArray = "{\"type\":\"array\", \"items\":{"
            + "\"name\": \"iprecord\","
            + "\"type\": \"record\","
            + "\"fields\": [" 
            + "{\"name\": \"ip\", \"type\": \"string\"},"
            + "{\"name\": \"count\", \"type\": \"long\"}"
            + "]}}";

    String schemaArraySup = "{\"namespace\": \"rdma.avro\", \"name\":\"ipsuper\", \"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{ \"name\":\"child\", \"type\": {\"type\":\"array\", \"items\":{"
            + "\"name\": \"iprecord\","
            + "\"type\": \"record\","
            + "\"fields\": [" 
            + "{\"name\": \"ip\", \"type\": \"string\"},"
            + "{\"name\": \"count\", \"type\": \"long\"}"
            + "]}}}]}";


    Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord>(props);

    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema recordSchema = parser.parse(schemaRecord);


    Schema.Parser parser2 = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema arrSchema = parser2.parse(schemaArray);

    Schema.Parser parser3 = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema arrSchemaSup = parser3.parse(schemaArraySup);


    GenericRecord page = new GenericData.Record(recordSchema);
    page.put("ip","ip100");
    page.put("count",100L);

    GenericRecord page2= new GenericData.Record(recordSchema);
    page2.put("ip","ip200");
    page2.put("count",200L);

    GenericArray av_arr =  new GenericData.Array(2,arrSchema);
    av_arr.add(page);
    av_arr.add(page2);

    GenericRecord pageSuper = new GenericData.Record(arrSchemaSup);
    pageSuper.put("child", av_arr);

    ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> data = new ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord>("avro_test2",pageSuper);

    producer.send(data).get();

    producer.close();
}
```

Comment: avro version? i do not see anything wrong with that code. or maybe you are missing some code. thanks

Comment: 1.8.2，I doubt Avro doesn't support Array with record as subtype, Do you have example code please?

Comment: i just executed your code :), can you paste the full code and dependecies? (btw, it does support array)

Comment: @halgos Could you please review my code, any improvement needed please?

Comment: I think you should update the questions, not it seems to be something different and is not clear what is the issue. Also, it would be great if you can reproduce any of that as an unittest, or at least make sure questions more clear

Comment: @hlagos I modified, could you please give some advices, the code looks messy and it might have potential bugs :)